# Sleep on unplugging with lid closed

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery

I want the machine to stay on when I close the lid when plugged in (keep things running overnight, etc.), so I have it set that way, but if I then unplug it with the lid down, it seems the power management system is overly literalistic. What I want is:

Lid closed + battery power = asleep

AFAICT, what happens instead is that unplugging the machine never causes a transition, which is … error-prone. (It's especially bad on my Dell XPS 15, which has no indicator when it's asleep, so it's often impossible to tell.) The computer should do what I want, not vice versa, so where do I hack it to do the right thing? I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 with a Cinnamon desktop.

Answer (score 0):

In the power setting of ubuntu, set it like that:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6JOF.png)

Especially the ***When the lid is closed***

set ***On battery power*** as  ***Suspend***

and ***When plugged in*** as ***Do nothing***

Comment: That's exactly how I have it set. But it only takes effect if I unplug it *and then* close the lid. If I close the lid first, it stays on (and then overheats in my backpack). Basically, only closing or opening the lid can trigger a shutdown.